# daily-motion scope issue ( delegate_account_management ,read_insights)

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

I have used these Daily-motion scope ( delegate_account_management ,read_insights ) and when I click the accept button it redirect's to the dailymotion's 404 page

http://prntscr.com/j06z8c

http://prntscr.com/j06qzr

Below is my code

```
$scopes = array('userinfo','email','manage_videos','read_insights','delegate_account_management');
$api->setGrantType(Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION, $apiKey, $apiSecret ,$scopes);
$access_data = $api->getAccessToken();
```

When i have not used the above scopes then its working fine. Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, I got no problem to get the scopes and your screenshots lacks a bit of information. I Suggest you to send a ticket to our support team using this form: [Support Form](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39467#new-request)

Please specify your API key (and only API key) in the ticket.